# Disable "Automatically detect settings" in IE proxy configuration

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer, proxy

When I boot up my corporate laptop, the "Automatically detect settings" option is ticked. This setting never works and I need to untick it before I can access the Internet.

I've tried looking for a registry entry so I can run a script on boot up that turns this setting off. I enabled the setting and exported a branch, then disabled the setting and exported. A diff comparison shows these two as identical between the two exports:

> [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet
>   Explorer]
>
> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet
>   Settings]

Does anyone know what the setting is? I'm running Windows 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might disable proxy caching, as described here:
[How to disable automatic proxy caching in Internet Explorer](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?id=271361)

It's also very puzzling that the following registry key doesn't change:
`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Connections`
As the difference is only one bit, it might have been overlooked.

See this thread for an example of differing values (skip to the very end):
[Registry key for IE's "Auto Detect Settings" option](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Operating_Systems/WinXP/Q_21433965.html)
Note: If you can't see the ending comment, search this article through [google](http://www.google.fr/search?q=Registry+key+for+IE%27s+%22Auto+Detect+Settings%22+option&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a) and click on it. This is a particularity of experts-exchange.com.
You can use the info in this thread to build a batch script to reset the registry to **your** correct values.

Comment: Though using someone else's registry settings is a bad idea for this unless you want their entire proxy server settings too, so you'll want to save your own registry setting out.

Comment: @Polsy: You're absolutely right. My intention was only to demonstrate that other people do see a difference. I've clarified my answer.

Comment: I logged in today and it worked fine. I'll keep testing and come back once confirmed.

Comment: Seems to be fixed with the first link you gave, thanks!

Comment: Short version: you need to clear the first bit of the ninth byte in that registry key, by taking 8 off its value, e.g. change "XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XB ..." to "XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX X3 ..." (or change 9 to 1, D to 5, or F to 7)